# python terraform wrapper pass the variable

Tags: python, terraform

i'm running a python wrapper to initiate terrafrom init plan and apply.
when i try to plan it asks for the region. which iam passing as second variable. but when i call in the function its erroring out. so basically my question is if i run terraform plan and if plan looks for the input i need to pass it as variable in python wrapper

while running the plan
python script --1st variable --2ndvariable
    terr = Terraform(dir=ter_dir)
    return_code, stdout, stderr = terr.init(region)
    print(return_code)
    print(stdout)
    if return_code == 0 or not stderr:
        return_code, stdout, stderr = terr.plan(1stvaraible).

got the error
Error at terraform plan: Failed to load Terraform configuration or plan: open us-east-1: no such file or directory

Comment: Can you provide more details? question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail and see how you are generating the terraform command, I will give it a try at telling you the correct format for the command and you can determine if you are doing that correctly.

When passing variables to terraform commands at the commandline you need to have this format.

```
terraform plan --var region=east-us-1 --var myVar=test
```

Hope that helps, and I am guessing you are not formatting your command that way.